# How to attach scene component to actor from the c++ code in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I need to attach a scene component to an actor but in a way that i will be able to access the things(function, variables) in the scene component from another actor. for example, i have an actor called Door1 and i have a scene component called DoorSceneComponent and i want to attach the DoorSceneComponent to the root of Door1 but in the c++ code, not in the Unreal Editor. I also have a Character class called PlayerCharacter in this class, i have a refrence to Door1, the thing is that i want to be able to call a function that is defiened in DoorSceneComponent from the PlayerCharacter class. My question is, how can i attach the DoorSceneComponent to Door1 in c++?
I use Unreal Engine 5.1
I use Manjaro Linux as my OS.
If you need any more information just say.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one takes a couple separate parts.
Firstly, you'll want to hold a pointer to an instance of your `DoorSceneComponent`. So in your Door1 header:

Door1.h

```
private: //(or protected, depending on your needs)
UPROPERTY()
DoorSceneComponent* DoorComp;
```

(If it has properties that need to be edited in the editor, then you'll need to add one of [these tags](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Properties/Specifiers/) to the UPROPERTY depending on what exact behaviour you require.)

In your Door1 constructor, you need to actually create the scene component:

Door1.cpp

```
ADoor1::ADoor1() {
    // Create the component
    DoorComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UDoorSceneComponent>(TEXT("Door Component));
    // Attach it to the root
    DoorComp->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
}
```

[CreateDefaultSubobject](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UObject/CreateDefaultSubobject/2/)

[SetupAttachment](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/SetupAttachment/)

Once you've done this and recompiled, the component will be attached in any blueprints/instances of your actor.